# Почему не добавляет новую строку?

Tags: javascript, строки, dom

Привет, есть такой вот код, но когда в консоли прописываешь addTask('Hello, World!') для добавления нового пункта оно высвечивает ошибку, что это пустая строка, что не так?

```js
let tasks = [
    "Выучить JavaScript",
    "Выучить Angular 4",
    "Выучить React"
];

let ul = document.querySelector('.list-group');

function listTemplate(task) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = task;
    li.className = 'list-group-item';
    return li;
}

function generateList(tasksArray) {
    clearList();

    for ( let i = 0; i < tasksArray.length; i++){
        let liTemplate = listTemplate(tasksArray[i]);
        ul.appendChild(liTemplate);
    }
}

function addTask(string) {
    if ( !string || typeof string !== 'string') return new Error('Не передана строка');
    if ( string.length ) return new Error('Строка не должна быть пустой');

    tasks.unshift(string);

    generateList(tasks);
}

function clearList() {
    ul.innerHTML = '';
}


generateList(tasks);
```

```html
<ul class=list-group></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что там должно быть

```
if(!string.length)
```

Похоже на очепятку

Comment: Точно, спасибо!